# Иерархия исключений

Tags: php, исключения

Хочу понять на сколько правильно строить подобную иерархию исключений. Есть базовый тип исключений от которого наследуются все остальные. К примеру файл `PackageException.php` в котором будет следующая структура. Нужно ли разбивать каждое исключение как отдельный файл или можно реализовать по структуре одного файла родительского в котором будут объявлены все остальные которые его наследуют

```
PackageException extends Exception  {}

PackageNotFoundException extends PackageException{}

PackageAlreadyExistsException extends PackageException{}
```

Comment: В контексте ООП - каждый файл. Чтобы не мешать всё в кучу. Тем более там может быть дополнительная логика в каждом классе. И тогда класс может занимать не 6-7 строк, а 67 или 607 :)) . Да и чисто логически  - быстрее найти файл по алфавиту в навигаторе, чем наименование класса в файле, чтобы внести какие-либо правки или удалить

Comment: Но вообще Невозможно дать объективный ответ)) потому что каждый пишет как ему удобнее :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Ну дополнительной логики не будет, просто для удобства отлова определенных ситуаций хочу все разбить по исключениям, чтобы проще было отлавливать кейсы и не городить кучу проверок

Comment: Ну, в Java например, всё в каждом файле. У нас в проекте тоже, не смотря на то, что в каждом может быть переопределён лишь базовый `$message`. + префикс свой для каждого эксепшна. А так: смотри второе сообщение :D

Comment: вопрос. для чего нужно наследовать PackageNotFoundException от PackageException?

Comment: @Ипатьев, Чтобы в случае чего не ловить каждое исключение по типу отдельно, а только родительский

Comment: ну вот вы и ответили себе на вопрос, "насколько правильно строить подобную иерархию исключений". А проблема "в одном файле определять все исключения или в разных" зависит только от того, сможет ли автолоадер найти нужный класс.

Comment: @Ипатьев, я использую composer версии 1.8 он генерирует без проблем. 2.0 уже ругается что каждый класс должен быть венесен в отдельный файл. Да верно сам и ответил на свой вопрос